# WebService (WS) POST in Play 2.0 - Scala

Tags: web-services, scala, post, playframework, playframework-2.0

When I try to pass a Map to a post, I get this error:

> Cannot write an instance of
>   scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] to
>   HTTP response. Try to define a
>   Writeable[scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String]]

Here is my post example:

```
WS.url("http://mysql/endpoint")
  .post(Map("email" -> "juju@juju.com")).map { response =>
    Logger.logger.debug("response: " + response.body)
  }
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the tips: you must send [Map[String, Seq[String]]](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/http/Writeable.scala#L73)

```
WS.url("http://mysql/endpoint")
  .post(Map("email" -> Seq("juju@juju.com"))).map { response =>
    Logger.logger.debug("response: " + response.body)
  }
```